# How to reference an attribute in loop in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following line of code in my jsp:

```
 <body>
These are the names of the companies you have searched for:

<c:forEach items="${cname}" var="company">
<br>
<a href="companyinfo">${company}</a>
<br>
</c:forEach> 


</body>
```

It gives me the following output on the web page:

```
company1
company2
company3
```

I want to click on company1 and want "company 1" displayed on console, however it is just null.

I used the following method in the servlet:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        dispatcher=req.getRequestDispatcher("/shareinfo.jsp");
        System.out.println(getServletContext().getAttribute("company"));
        dispatcher.forward(req, resp);

    }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: are you setting an ServletContext attribute? if not, then value is null, but i think you are looking more for request.getParameter("company")

Comment: i did not set the attribute, I tried: System.out.println(req.getParameter("company")); but it was still null;

Comment: I don't see any code which is sending data to the servlet. Have you missed this from your post?

Comment: assuming that companyinfo is your servlet use this tag:
   <a href="companyinfo?company=${company}">${company}</a> then in servlet print out request.getParameter("company")

Comment: the above answer works, however i cant select it as best answer.